# How to make docker container be notified when volume from another container was updated?

Tags: docker, deployment, docker-compose, docker-cloud, data-containers

I have docker container with Nginx and data container with static (JS,CSS) files only.
At app start Nginx mounts volume from data container using volume_from.
The problem appears when I want to update my static files because Nginx container can't see that volume has changed.
Is it possible to fetch static volume changes without restarting Nginx container?

```
proxy:
  image: proxy
  volumes_from:
    - static:ro
  ports:
    - "80:80"
  restart: always
  sequential_deployment: true
static:
  image: static
  volumes:
    - /home/node/static/build
  read_only: true
  command: "true"
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this problem from VirtualBox.. you could try to add this into your nginx.conf:

```
sendfile off;
```

[Nginx Docs](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/?highlight=sendfile)